# Parsing an INI file to runtime properties

Tags: c#

Currently I am developing an application which uses a few variables which should be changable in a .ini file. Since I want to make the application to be able to continue if the user "forgets" to correctly implement the variables (read: "retard-proof"), I figured I would have to create an object for each variable which holds a default value and an optional set value. My implementation looks like this at the moment;

**IProperty.cs**

```
public interface IProperty
{
    bool IsSet { get; set; }
    string PropertyName { get; set; }
    object GetValue();
}
```

**Property.cs**

```
public class Property<T> : IProperty
{
    public bool IsSet { get; set; }

    public Property()
    {
        IsSet = false;
    }

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public T DefaultValue { get; set; }

    private T _CurrentValue;
    public T CurrentValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _CurrentValue;
        }
        set
        {
            IsSet = true;
            _CurrentValue = value;
        }
    }

    private T GetActualValue()
    {
        return IsSet ? CurrentValue : DefaultValue;
    }

    public object GetValue()
    {
        return (object)GetActualValue();
    }
}
```

**PropertyFactory.cs**

```
public static class PropertyFactory
{
    private static Dictionary<string, IProperty> CreateDefaults()
    {
        Dictionary<string, IProperty> dic = new Dictionary<string, IProperty>();
        List<IProperty> propList = new List<IProperty>();

        #region String properties
        propList.Add(new Property<string>(){ DefaultValue = @"C:\...\...", PropertyName = "log_path"});
        //...                      
        #endregion

        #region Int32 properties
        propList.Add(new Property<int>() { DefaultValue = 1337, PropertyName = "some_value"});         
        //...   
        #endregion

        #region Boolean properties
        propList.Add(new Property<bool>() { DefaultValue = false, PropertyName = "log_enabled" });
        //...
        #endregion

        //Map to the dictionary based on their name
        foreach(IProperty prop in propList)
        {
            dic.Add(prop.PropertyName, prop);
        }

        return dic;
    }

    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, IProperty> CreateFromFile(string path)
    {
        Dictionary<string, IProperty> dic = CreateDefaults();
        INIFile ini = new INIFile(path);
        Dictionary<string, string> values = ini.GetAllValues();

        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in values)
        {
            if (dic.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
            {
                if (dic[pair.Key] is Property<int>)
                {
                    int value;
                    if (!int.TryParse(pair.Value, out value)) continue;
                    ((Property<int>)dic[pair.Key]).CurrentValue = value;
                }

                if (dic[pair.Key] is Property<string>)
                {
                    ((Property<string>)dic[pair.Key]).CurrentValue = pair.Value;
                }

                if (dic[pair.Key] is Property<bool>)
                {
                    bool valueIsValid = (pair.Value == "true" || pair.Value == "false");
                    if (!valueIsValid) continue;
                    ((Property<bool>)dic[pair.Key]).CurrentValue = (pair.Value == "true");

                }
            }
        }
        ConcurrentDictionary<string, IProperty> cdic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IProperty>(dic);
        return cdic;
    }
}
```

**INIFile.cs**

```
public class INIFile
{
    private string _path;

    public INIFile(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetAllValues()
    {
        string s;
        string name;
        string val;

        Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_path)
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine() ?? "").Contains("="))
                {
                    name = s.Split('=')[0];
                    val = s.Split('=')[1];
                    map.Add(name, val);
                }
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

And finally, the implementation in the actual project;

```
public static class Properties
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, IProperty> PropertyList = PropertyFactory.CreateFromFile(@"C:\...\...\settings.ini");
}
```

I am not satisfied with the current implementation of `Property<T>`. It requires alot of (un)boxing and that looks ugly. For example;

```
if((bool)Properties.PropertyList["log_enabled"].GetValue()) //log...
```

However, I could not come up with a better implementation to map all the properties in one `ConcurrentDictionary<>`. Is there a better/nicer way to do this? Also, note that the `PropertyList` has to be accessed by multiple threads; hence my choice of `ConcurrentDictionary<>`.

Answer (score 3):

**Naming**

Variables named `s` and `sr` are unhelpful to a maintenance programmer, prefer longer, more explanatory names.

I also prefer to declare my variables where I'm going to be using them (e.g. s inside your first while loop) so that the declaration is never too far from the utilisation.

**Var**

Use `var` when declaring local variables when the right hand side of the declaration makes the type obvious.

e.g.

```
Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

should be

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

You should also always use `var` when declaring a loop variable.

```
foreach(var pair in values)
```

**Lines**

Lines like this:

```
propList.Add(new Property<string>(){ DefaultValue = @"C:\...\...", PropertyName = "log_path"});
```

Could do with expanding across multiple lines, it eases readability and stops you having to scroll.

Result:

```
propList.Add(new Property<string>()
{ 
    DefaultValue = @"C:\...\...",
    PropertyName = "log_path"
});
```

**Regions**

Regions are controversial outside of methods, but whenever I see a region *inside* a method it's almost a sure-fire guarantee that the contents of that region should be refactored into its own method. You're missing some lines from your original code, so that would be a judgement call left to you.

**Generics**

As for your complaint:

```
if((bool)Properties.PropertyList["log_enabled"].GetValue()) //log...
```

Why on earth does `GetValue()` even exist?

Why not just use the generic `GetActualValue()` in your interface?

```
public interface IProperty
{
    bool IsSet { get; set; }
    string PropertyName { get; set; }
    T GetValue<T>();
}
```

Then call `GetValue<bool>()` and have it return a boolean, no boxing or unboxing needed.

If it's the wrong type, either throw an exception, or sort something out with null values.

Comment: `T GetValue<T>()` was the obvious missing part of my puzzle. I tried `T GetValue()`, but that would've meant that I needed `IProperty<T>`, which did not fit in my design. Thanks for that one! I also tend to forget te use `var`, I'll take it into account. About the regions; there are like 20 lines in total. It was just meant to get it organized, however, they are not neccessary. Would you create methods like `CreateIntDefaults()` and others there?

Comment: @DionV.: For the defaults, you might even consider just adding the values in the declaration: `var propList = new List<IProperty> { new Property<string>() { DefaultValue = @"C:\...\...", PropertyName = "log_path"}, // etc };` perhaps all in a separate `List<IProperty> GetDefaults()` method, which returns your full defaults collection. I'd argue that such a method is only doing one thing, and therefore needs no more splitting than that.